# Don't find provisioning profile to export ipa

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, provisioning

I have a problem to export a ipa with xcode4. I compile the app with a provisioning profile without problems, and archive it. When I choose "Distrubute ... -> Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deploy" don't find the provisioning profile with which I compiled the app.

Any idea for fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked that the appropriate Provisioning Profile is still available to build with? Often the selected Profile stated out in the target is already missing but kept in the list. 
Also check your Provisioning Profiles in the Organiser for duplicates, missing certificates and expired profiles... Delete all of them, add the profile you need if it is not available and try again!

Comment: Yes, I checked all that and the problem persists :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the bundle ID in your `Info.plist` file matches the bundle ID for the provisioning profile.

Comment: Bundle id is correct, i can compile without problem, but the provisioning profile don't appear to export ipa